# control source, look for multiple values

Tags: report, ms-access-2010

I need to specify the control source property on a report so that it counts the number of female-headed single parent households.

the logic is: Sex="F", Marital=Single OR Divorced OR Separated OR Widowed, Kid >0

In the control source property, I entered:

=Abs(Sum([Sex]="F" And [Marital] IN ("Single", ”Divorced”, “Widowed”, ”Separated”) And [Kid]>0))

What am I doing wrong? Thank you. Just getting started with ACCESS.

Answer (score 0):

*IN* is for SQL only, so try:

```
=Abs(Sum([Sex]="F" And ([Marital]="Single" Or [Marital]="Divorced" Or [Marital]="Widowed" Or [Marital]="Separated") And [Kid]>0))
```

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. I appreciate the suggestion though.

Comment: Can't tell. We have no info other than what you provide.

Comment: problem solved! I coded the derivation at the data level, so that the report doesn't have to do the work.

Comment: Great! Have a nice weekend.